# Using a while loop to call a method based on the argument received?

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, while-loop

I'm having trouble logically trying to figure out how I would do this. I might be going at it at the completely wrong approach. This example I will provide is what I would LIKE to have, but I know it's completely flawed now, and not sure if I could add some type of `List` to help.

```
public int getNumber(int num){
  int counter;
  counter = 1;
  while (counter < 5){ // 5 because that's the number of methods I have
    if (num == counter){
      //CALL THE APPROPRIATE METHOD
    }
    counter++;
  }
}
```

The issue I'm having is: Methods of course are called by their name, not by any number.
How would I go about calling method 3 if the argument received was 3. The logic would stop the `while` loop at 3, but what would I use in the `if statement` if my methods were as followed:

```
public Object methodOne(){
  //actions
 }
public Object methodTwo(){
  //actions
 }
public Object methodThree(){
  //actions
 }
public Object methodFour(){
  //actions
 }
public Object methodFive(){
  //actions
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the question is not clear enough .. what do you exactly want to impolement.. tell us in clear words

Comment: Looks like you need to explore using java reflection: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: @StinePike Whats the sense in being so rude? Sure I'm still discovering new things, and I'm not to deep into Java, but I'm still in high school, and I'm just trying to discover a condensed way to run 1 of about a dozen methods, based on what argument was passed. I'm going to flag you for being rude and offensive. Thanks for taking time out of your day to leave your opinion, though.

Comment: @user2388169 .. sorry for my last comment.. didn't want to hurt you .. i apologies for my misunderstanding. .. cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok According to your commment at Quetzalcoatl's answer here is my answer

you can use java reflection to call a method by name. For example

```
public int getNumber(int num) {
            String methodName = "method" + num;
            Method n = getClass().getMethod(methodName);
            n.invoke(this);
}
```

so your method will be like

`method1()`, `method2()` etc.

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like you've tried to implement your own version of a `switch` statement.

Perhaps you should try:

```
public int getNumber(int num) {
  switch(num) {
    case 1:
      //call method one
      break;
    case 2:
      //call method two
      break;
    //etc
    default:
      //handle unsupported num
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks exactly like what I'd need, but my issue is, There will potentially be dozens of `case`'s. Is there's a more condensed way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

A brute-force answer:

```
Object result;
switch(num){
    case 1: result = methodOne(); break;
    case 2: result = methodTwo(); break;
    case 3: result = methodThree(); break;
    case 4: result = methodFour(); break;
    case 5: result = methodFive(); break;
    default: result = null; break;
}
```

A reflection answer

```
static final String methodNames[] = { "methodOne", "methodTwo", "methodThree", 
        "methodFour", "methodFive" };

Object result = getClass().getMethod(methodNames[num - 1]).invoke(this);
```